# Get all decimal places in a number after division in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, math, decimal

Since after dividing, multiplying, adding, or subtracting, JavaScript tends to cut down the number of decimal places shown as a result. Is there a way to get **ALL** of the decimal places? If there isn't a simple way to do this, is there a library that can do so?

Comment: `showAllDecimalPlaces(Math.PI)`

Comment: 10 / 3 is *quite* long

Comment: You probably mean "as many as I need" decimal places, not "all" of them. There's no such feature built-in in javascript, but libraries exist: search for "arbitrary precision" or "big math".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you need a higher precision than the precision of the JavaScript Number (about 16 digits), you will need to use bignumbers.

With [math.js](http://mathjs.org) you can do something like:

```
var math = mathjs({decimals: 100});
var a = math.bignumber(2);
var b = math.bignumber(3);
var c = math.divide(a, b);

console.log(math.format(c));
```

This will output:

> 0.6666666666666666666666666666666666666666666666666666666666666666666666666666666666666666666666666667